# On the intersection of Bouligand cones

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, set-valued-analysis

Let $K, L$ be two closed convex subsets of the normed space $X$. If 
$$
0 \in \operatorname{Int}(K-L)
$$

Prove that 
$$
\forall x \in K \cap L \Rightarrow T_{L \cap K}(x)=T_{K}(x) \cap T_{L}(x)
$$
In which $T_{A}(x)$ is the Bouligand cone to $A$ at $x \in A$.

Let's recall that $y \in T_{A}(x)$ iff there exist $(x_n) \subset A$ and $(\lambda_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ satisfying
\begin{cases}
x_n \longrightarrow x \\ 
\lambda_n(x_n-x) \longrightarrow y
\end{cases}
I have dealt with the easy inclusion $T_{L \cap K}(x) \subset T_{K}(x)\cap T_{L}(x)$.

For the other inclusion, let $z \in T_{K}(x)\cap T_{L}(x)$ then there exist $(x_n) \subset K, (y_n) \subset L, (\lambda_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $(\mu_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ satisfying
\begin{cases}
x_n \longrightarrow x \\ 
\lambda_n(x_n-x) \longrightarrow z
\end{cases}
and
\begin{cases}
y_n \longrightarrow x \\ 
\mu_n(y_n-x) \longrightarrow z
\end{cases}
We have to find a sequence $(z_n) \subset L \cap K$ and a sequence $(\gamma_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ so that 
\begin{cases} 
z_n \longrightarrow x \\ 
\gamma_n(z_n-x) \longrightarrow z
\end{cases}
My idea is as follows:

If the set $A=\left\{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n=y_n \right\}$ is infinite, we can easily construct a subsequence of $(x_n)$ satisfying the required thing.

In the case that $A$ is finite, I know we have to use the assumptions that $K$ and $L$ are two closed convex set and that $0 \in \operatorname{Int}(K-L)$ but I'm stuck here.

Anybody can help me? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check out the book by Aubin and Frankowska which should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume $w \in T_{K}(x) \cap T_{L}(x)$ but $w \notin T_{L \cap K}(x)$. Now use strong separation.

Comment: could you present what you said more clearly? I don't have too much knowledge about convex analysis. Thanks!!

Comment: @Noname Separation theorem of convex sets in finite dimensions. It's a very basic and important theorem of convex analysis.